# ImageView getting very small under a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

In one of my screens, I expect to acheive this kind of a layout
[image: What I want]

Highest importance being the images correctly scaled. These images i am giving are of adequate resolution and works fine on another fragment layout.
My layout.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stadiumbg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_item"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="70%"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="80%"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_item"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vote" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Down Vote" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything else is great. The drawable listview_item is something that has been given to provided rounded corners, and tested in a listview with the above said images. Perfectly fine.
But in this layout, both the images gets super downscaled. It is like this.

[image]

wasting all that space for no reason. 
What I have tried:
adjustViewBounds set to false
Scaletype as fitXY

Any idea to get What I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the width and height of the ImageView. Instead of:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Use:

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Change the numbers to fit what you want.

Comment: But that would be a problem when it is in lower resolution phones isnt it?

Comment: No it won't. dp stands for Density-independent Pixels.

Comment: I tried it. I set 200dp on my nexus. The images become substancially big, but the text overlaps on the image, (text1 and text2).. So, i reduce it and bring it correct at say, 100dp. lets say it works fine on my nexus now, now on a smaller sceen, it may still overlap na?

Comment: I use it all the time and I have tried it on Note 3 and a 2.8 inches phone, it works.